# Essential Macintosh Tools

Tags: mac, repair, diagnostic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some “must have” Mac OS X programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs)

What are some tools you use a lot to diagnose and fix Macs?

I'll start the ball rolling

[Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html)

Quick and easy tool for finding out the temperature of various components. Apple put lots of sensors inside so it's quite informative

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)

A Mac equivalent of Treesize. Not as good as Treesize but does the job eventually.

Answer (score 0):

[Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php)
The best multipurpose tool I've used.

Answer (score 0):

[DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) is also a good tool for HDD recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I like Onyx: http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/20070